# In Sails.JS, Is it possible to populate more than one attribute for a Model?

Tags: sails.js

For a given model named "Message"

```
module.exports = {
  attributes:{
    subject: {type: 'string', required: true},
    body: {type: 'string', required: true},
    from: {model: 'user, required: true},
    to: {model: 'user', required: true},
  }
}
```

The following find populates the attribute "from"

```
let msg = Message.find({id:1}).populate('from');
```

Is it possible to populate both "from" and "to" attributes for that find ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, just call populate twice.

```
let msg = Message.find({id:1}).populate('from').populate('to');
```